# After installing media9 install I get \prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn etc as undefined control sequence

Tags: installing, media9

I have attempted to install media9 and seem to have done it as per https://gitlab.com/agrahn/media9 then I have included some videos in a latex/beamer document but on compile I get Undefined control sequence`\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \regex_match:nn{nV}{TF}`. The compiled file is full of gibberish.

The source code to include the video is here:

```
\begin{frame}
\includemedia[
  label=vidA,
  addresource=latticetrimmed.mp4,
  activate=pageopen,
  width=5cm, height=4cm,
  flashvars={
     source=latticetrimmed.mp4
    &loop=true
  }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\includemedia[
  label=vidB,
  addresource=latticewithshortcutstrimmed.mp4,
  activate=pageopen,
  width=5cm, height=4cm,
  flashvars={
     source=latticewithshortcutstrimmed.mp4
    &loop=true
  }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\mediabutton[
  mediacommand=vidA:playPause,
  mediacommand=vidB:playPause
]{\fbox{Play/Pause}}
\end{frame}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Updating packages by hand is usually not a good idea, as this type of conflict can happen. For this one you may try updating the l3kernel too: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How else can I install it if not manually? I use teashop on a mac, my version is Version 4.42 (4.42). Does media9 come as default somehow?

Comment: Usually you update/install a package using the package manager of your TeX distribution. Which one do you use (TeXLive, MacTeX, MiKTeX, or some other)?

Comment: Thanks @Phelype Oleinik, updating l3kernel seem to work. I am not too sure how to check the package manager on my mac. The only issue is that the quality of the video in the resulting PDF is worse than wen using \movie with the \usepackage{multimideia}.

Comment: Glad it worked :-) To find out which distribution you use, open the log file of any document you compiled and look at the very first line. For me, using TeXLive on windows it says: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX)`. What does it say to you?